# Keyframe Bezier Not Synched

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes

I have two properties keyframed, call em A & B. They both go form point 1 to point 2 from 0 to 90, but B also goes from point 2 to piont 3, from 90 to 130. But as a result of this, property B has a different speed than A over the trajectory 1 - 2, and thus isn't in sync.

How can I fix this? I want both properties to have the same speed from piont 1 to piont 2.

I hope this isn't too confusing

Comment: in the graph editor you could either: switch to linear interpolation if point 2 is on the line formed by point 1 and piont 3; insert a keyframe to B at point 2

Comment: If I put extrapolation and interpolation on linear, it works. But ideally Id have an ease in bezier at the start for both properties, but at the same speed, such that the second property just continues at that same speed.

Comment: in which case you'll have to add a keyframe to B at point 2 and rotate/scale the handle to match A

Comment: That did turn out to be the solution, thanks